# How can I redirect to a page according to a dbquery

Tags: javascript, sql, razor, asp-classic

Here is the code I'm trying to use

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
    var sqlquery = "SELECT Dep FROM UserProfile WHERE Email = @0";
  }

@if(db.Query(sqlquery,WebSecurity.CurrentUserName) = "Quebec")
{
   Response.Redirect("~/Members/Quebec/Quebec");
            return;
}
else if(db.Query(sqlquery,WebSecurity.CurrentUserName) = "Laval")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Members/Laval/Laval");
                return;
}
```

It gives me a CS0131 error... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not perform data access functions inside of a view. This is very very bad. At least if it is done in the controller you can `return RedirectToAction("blah");`

Comment: I guess he is using WebMatrix and not ASP.NET MVC. In WebMatrix you do not have such notion as controllers or actions. You only have a tag soup inside your templates. Unfortunately the OP didn't properly tagged his question (he even tagged his question with `asp-classic` and `javascript` for Christ's sake) so we can only be guessing the technology he is using from the source code he provided (which by the way doesn't quite look like `asp-classic` or `javascript`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`QuerySingle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.querysingle%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) and bear in mind that in C# the operator to test equality is `==`, not `=` (which is the assignment operator):

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
    string sqlquery = "SELECT Dep FROM UserProfile WHERE Email = @0";
    string result = (string)db.QuerySingle(sqlquery, WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);
}

@if (result == "Quebec")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Members/Quebec/Quebec");
}
else if (result == "Laval")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Members/Laval/Laval");
}
```

If you do not have an unique constraint over the `Email` column then you could use the [`Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.query%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method but get the first result for example (using `FirstOrDefault`). But that would really depend on your specific database design.

Comment: I'm getting this error now:
Exception Details:   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert type 'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' to 'string'

Source Error: 


    Line 2:      var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
    Line 3:      string sqlquery = "SELECT Dep FROM UserProfile WHERE Email = @0";
    Line 4:      string result = (string)db.QuerySingle(sqlquery, WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);
    Line 5:  }
    Line 6:

Comment: Thank you it worked ! For someone who doesn't speak english very well and is self learning, people like you are gold =D